# how to show that two stets of vectors have the same linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, education

> Let $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_3=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $v_4=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\-2\end{bmatrix}$
>
> $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$
>
> $T=\{v_1,v_2,v_4\}$
>
> Show that the set of all linear combinations of vectors from $S$ is the same as the set of all linear combinations of vectors from $T$.

how to show that two stets of vectors have the same linear combinations?

Comment: Please add your attempt in question itself. Question without attempt are very unpopular on this website.

Comment: i attached an image contains the whole attempt

Comment: Attaching images on the StackExchange network is quite unpopular unless you really want to show a picture (graph, drawing, photo, screenshot etc.). To type mathematical formulas this web site supports "Math Jax".

Comment: Hint: You'll first have to show that $v_3$ can be written as linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_4$.

Comment: After showing that v3 can be written as linear combination of v1,v2,v4. Then what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\quad$  Actually, the linear combination of vectors contained in T should be linear combination of that of S. What we want to prove is to get $ \vec{v}_3 $ could be wrote as a linear combination of {$\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2, \vec{v}_4$}. Because you have done this process. Therefore, we go ahead. We will use a example to illustrate the principle. 
   Example: If $ \vec{v}_3  = \vec{v}_1 + \vec{v}_2 + \vec{v}_4$, then any vector expressed in term of  {$\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2, \vec{v}_3, \vec{v}_4 $} could be expressed in term of {$\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2,  \vec{v}_4 $}. Since $\vec{x} = x_1\vec{v}_1+x_2 \vec{v}_2+x_3 \vec{v}_3+x_4 \vec{v}_4 =x_1\vec{v}_1+x_2 \vec{v}_2+x_3( \vec{v}_1 + \vec{v}_2 + \vec{v}_4)+x_4 \vec{v}_4= (x_1+x_3)\vec{v}_1+(x_2+x_3) \vec{v}_2+(x_4+x_3) \vec{v}_4$.